# oracle to_date function manipulation

Tags: sql, database, oracle, date-arithmetic

I would like to use sql query to do some manipulation like display today date + 3, it means if today day is 2013-03-09 , so adds 3 days it will be 2013-03-12.

it is my sample table :

```
PLACES(VARCHAR)   TMS(NUMBER)
LONDON            20130301
TAIWAN            20130302
```

I have to use to_date function to convert it to be date format.

```
select to_char(to_date(TMS,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD') from city;
```

The result :

```
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TMS,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD')
2013-03-01
2013-03-02
```

I have tried as below:

```
select to_char(to_date(TMS+3,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD') from city;
```

But it cannot work. Any hints ? Thanks

Comment: Just to be clear, 20130301+3 would devliver something which can be cast to 04-MAR-2013 but 20130228+3 won't deliver 03-MAR-2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select to_char(to_date(TMS,'YYYY-MM-DD')+3,'YYYY-MM-DD') from city;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you..

```
select to_char(to_date(TMS,'YYYY-MM-DD')+ INTERVAL '3' DAY,'YYYY-MM-DD') from city;
```

Comment: it works perfectly but if the interval '3' is more than 100 , it throws an error "ORA-01873: the leading precision of the interval is too small"

Comment: if you want day to be greater than 100 you can use month also, same thing DAY to be changes to MONTH